# List of dataframes with different column names to a single pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have list of 3 dataframes of stock tickers and prices I want to convert into a single dataframe.

dataframes:

```
[          Date   AMBU-B.CO     BAVA.CO    CARL-B.CO      CHR.CO   COLO-B.CO  \
 0   2020-01-02  112.500000  172.850006   984.400024  525.599976  814.000000   
 1   2020-01-03  111.300003  171.199997   989.799988  526.799988  812.000000   
 2   2020-01-06  108.150002  166.100006  1001.000000  519.599976  820.200012   
 3   2020-01-07  110.500000  170.000000  1002.000000  522.400024  823.599976   
 4   2020-01-08  109.599998  171.399994   993.000000  510.399994  820.000000   
 ..         ...         ...         ...          ...         ...         ...   
 308 2021-03-25  270.000000  295.200012   965.799988  562.599976  964.200012   
 309 2021-03-26  271.299988  302.000000   974.599976  548.599976  954.000000   
 310 2021-03-29  281.000000  294.000000   981.400024  575.000000  968.200012   
 311 2021-03-30  280.899994  282.600006   986.599976  567.400024  950.200012   
 312 2021-03-31  297.899994  286.399994   974.599976  576.400024  953.799988   
 
       DANSKE.CO   DEMANT.CO       DSV.CO      FLS.CO  ...     NETC.CO  \
 0    110.349998  208.600006   769.799988  272.500000  ...  314.000000   
 1    107.900002  206.600006   751.400024  267.899994  ...  313.000000   
 2    106.699997  206.500000   752.400024  265.600006  ...  309.799988   
 3    107.750000  204.399994   753.799988  273.399994  ...  309.200012   
 4    108.250000  205.600006   755.799988  268.000000  ...  309.200012   
 ..          ...         ...          ...         ...  ...         ...   
 308  117.349998  260.399994  1170.000000  230.199997  ...  603.000000   
 309  120.050003  267.600006  1212.500000  237.800003  ...  603.500000   
 310  118.750000  267.100006  1206.000000  238.300003  ...  599.000000   
 311  120.500000  265.500000  1213.500000  243.600006  ...  592.000000   
 312  118.699997  268.700012  1244.500000  243.100006  ...  604.000000   
 
       NOVO-B.CO   NZYM-B.CO    ORSTED.CO   PNDORA.CO    RBREW.CO  ROCK-B.CO  \
 0    388.700012  327.100006   681.000000  293.000000  603.000000     1584.0   
 1    383.200012  322.500000   677.400024  293.200012  605.200012     1567.0   
 2    382.049988  321.200012   670.200012  328.200012  601.599976     1547.0   
 3    381.700012  322.000000   662.000000  339.299988  612.200012     1546.0   
 4    382.500000  322.700012   645.000000  343.600006  602.200012     1531.0   
 ..          ...         ...          ...         ...         ...        ...   
 308  425.450012  403.399994   983.000000  655.799988  658.400024     2506.0   
 309  423.549988  404.100006  1013.500000  666.400024  666.599976     2672.0   
 310  431.549988  404.000000  1013.000000  678.400024  669.799988     2650.0   
 311  430.700012  401.500000   998.799988  678.400024  672.000000     2632.0   
 312  429.750000  406.299988  1024.500000  679.599976  663.400024     2674.0   
 
      SIM.CO     TRYG.CO       VWS.CO  
 0     776.0  196.399994   659.400024  
 1     764.5  195.600006   648.599976  
 2     751.5  195.000000   648.400024  
 3     753.5  200.000000   639.599976  
 4     762.0  197.500000   645.400024  
 ..      ...         ...          ...  
 308   769.0  145.300003  1138.500000  
 309   775.5  146.500000  1187.000000  
 310   772.0  149.000000  1217.000000  
 311   781.0  149.800003  1245.000000  
 312   785.5  149.600006  1302.000000  
 
 [313 rows x 26 columns],
           Date    1COV.DE      ADS.DE      ALV.DE     BAS.DE    BAYN.DE  \
 0   2020-01-02  42.180000  291.549988  221.500000  68.290001  73.519997   
 1   2020-01-03  41.900002  291.950012  219.050003  67.269997  72.580002   
 2   2020-01-06  39.889999  289.649994  217.699997  66.269997  71.739998   
 3   2020-01-07  40.130001  294.750000  218.199997  66.300003  72.129997   
 4   2020-01-08  40.830002  302.850006  218.300003  65.730003  74.000000   
 ..         ...        ...         ...         ...        ...        ...   
 314 2021-03-29  56.439999  264.100006  214.600006  70.029999  53.360001   
 315 2021-03-30  58.200001  265.000000  219.050003  71.879997  53.750000   
 316 2021-03-31  57.340000  266.200012  217.050003  70.839996  53.959999   
 317 2021-04-01  57.660000  267.950012  217.649994  71.629997  53.419998   
 318 2021-04-01  57.660000  267.950012  217.649994  71.629997  53.419998   
 
          BEI.DE     BMW.DE      CON.DE     DAI.DE  ...     IFX.DE      LIN.DE  \
 0    105.650002  74.220001  116.400002  49.974998  ...  20.684999  190.050003   
 1    105.650002  73.320000  113.980003  49.070000  ...  20.389999  185.300003   
 2    106.000000  73.050003  112.680000  48.805000  ...  20.045000  183.600006   
 3    105.750000  74.220001  115.120003  49.195000  ...  21.040001  185.300003   
 4    106.199997  74.410004  117.339996  49.470001  ...  21.309999  185.850006   
 ..          ...        ...         ...        ...  ...        ...         ...   
 314   90.220001  85.599998  111.949997  73.709999  ...  34.880001  237.000000   
 315   90.040001  88.800003  113.449997  75.940002  ...  35.535000  238.500000   
 316   90.099998  88.470001  112.699997  76.010002  ...  36.154999  238.899994   
 317   90.500000  89.519997  112.760002        NaN  ...  36.570000  238.699997   
 318   90.500000  89.519997  112.760002  74.970001  ...  36.570000  238.699997   
 
          MRK.DE      MTX.DE     MUV2.DE     RWE.DE      SAP.DE      SIE.DE  \
 0    106.000000  258.100006  265.899994  26.959999  122.000000  118.639999   
 1    107.250000  257.799988  262.600006  26.840000  120.459999  116.360001   
 2    108.400002  258.000000  262.700012  26.450001  119.559998  115.820000   
 3    109.500000  262.299988  264.500000  27.049999  120.099998  116.559998   
 4    111.300003  263.000000  265.000000  27.170000  120.820000  117.040001   
 ..          ...         ...         ...        ...         ...         ...   
 314  145.949997  196.199997  260.200012  32.709999  104.300003  137.839996   
 315  145.949997  201.300003  265.000000  32.400002  103.559998  141.080002   
 316  145.800003  200.699997  262.600006  33.419998  104.419998  140.000000   
 317  145.800003  206.199997  266.049988  34.060001  106.000000  141.020004   
 318  145.800003  206.199997  266.049988  34.060001  106.000000  141.020004   
 
         VNA.DE     VOW3.DE  
 0    48.419998  180.500000  
 1    48.599998  176.639999  
 2    48.450001  176.619995  
 3    48.709999  176.059998  
 4    48.970001  176.820007  
 ..         ...         ...  
 314  55.599998  229.750000  
 315  55.619999  240.550003  
 316  55.700001  238.600006  
 317  56.099998  235.850006  
 318  56.099998  235.850006  
 
 [319 rows x 31 columns],
           Date      ADE.OL    AKRBP.OL  BAKKA.OL      DNB.OL     EQNR.OL  \
 0   2020-01-02  106.800003  289.000000     664.0  165.800003  177.949997   
 1   2020-01-03  108.199997  292.899994     670.0  164.850006  180.949997   
 2   2020-01-06  107.000000  296.299988     654.0  164.899994  185.000000   
 3   2020-01-07  111.199997  295.700012     657.5  163.899994  183.000000   
 4   2020-01-08  108.800003  295.299988     668.5  166.000000  183.600006   
 ..         ...         ...         ...       ...         ...         ...   
 310 2021-03-25  133.000000  237.500000     633.0  178.050003  164.449997   
 311 2021-03-26  133.300003  244.199997     640.0  181.449997  167.649994   
 312 2021-03-29  131.100006  248.199997     660.0  182.000000  169.750000   
 313 2021-03-30  126.900002  244.800003     672.0  182.500000  168.600006   
 314 2021-03-31  125.900002  242.800003     677.5  182.000000  167.300003   
 
          GJF.OL     LSG.OL     MOWI.OL       NAS.OL  ...     NHY.OL  \
 0    184.149994  59.240002  229.500000  4094.000000  ...  33.410000   
 1    185.100006  58.900002  229.800003  3986.000000  ...  32.660000   
 2    182.550003  59.000000  229.199997  3857.000000  ...  32.299999   
 3    184.600006  59.000000  227.199997  3964.000000  ...  32.220001   
 4    184.199997  59.700001  226.699997  3964.000000  ...  32.090000   
 ..          ...        ...         ...          ...  ...        ...   
 310  199.199997  70.680000  205.500000    53.299999  ...  50.060001   
 311  200.000000  71.959999  208.000000    53.020000  ...  53.080002   
 312  200.600006  73.099998  209.699997    55.000000  ...  53.060001   
 313  200.399994  73.419998  210.800003    60.759998  ...  53.419998   
 314  200.600006  73.099998  212.199997    66.400002  ...  54.759998   
 
         ORK.OL     SALM.OL    SCATC.OL     SCHA.OL     STB.OL     SUBC.OL  \
 0    89.959999  454.000000  123.400002  271.299988  69.900002  105.900002   
 1    89.699997  453.899994  123.000000  272.100006  69.500000  107.150002   
 2    89.139999  453.500000  117.300003  268.299988  68.639999  108.150002   
 3    89.879997  447.700012  116.000000  272.299988  69.720001  107.699997   
 4    87.720001  451.799988  118.400002  271.899994  70.139999  107.250000   
 ..         ...         ...         ...         ...        ...         ...   
 310  84.000000  568.799988  235.000000  368.200012  81.779999   87.800003   
 311  84.400002  581.799988  237.600006  375.700012  83.860001   87.000000   
 312  84.839996  585.000000  244.600006  367.399994  84.540001   87.820000   
 313  84.800003  587.400024  246.399994  361.000000  85.400002   87.279999   
 314  83.839996  590.000000  258.600006  359.000000  86.139999   85.900002   
 
          TEL.OL      TOM.OL      YAR.OL  
 0    157.649994  287.799988  361.299988  
 1    158.800003  284.399994  356.000000  
 2    159.399994  280.000000  356.000000  
 3    156.850006  274.000000  351.399994  
 4    155.449997  278.600006  357.299988  
 ..          ...         ...         ...  
 310  149.350006  376.200012  438.000000  
 311  149.050003  376.700012  444.000000  
 312  151.000000  378.500000  448.500000  
 313  150.600006  372.799988  447.200012  
 314  150.500000  370.299988  444.799988  
 
 [315 rows x 21 columns]]
```

I found out that to solve this one usually uses pd.concat, but this does not seem to work for me:

```
df = pd.concat(dataframes)
df
```

It seems to return a lot of NANs, and it should not. How to solve this? If it can help, all dataframes uses the same dates from 2020-01-02 to 2021-03-31.

```
Date    AMBU-B.CO   BAVA.CO CARL-B.CO   CHR.CO  COLO-B.CO   DANSKE.CO   DEMANT.CO   DSV.CO  FLS.CO  ... NHY.OL  ORK.OL  SALM.OL SCATC.OL    SCHA.OL STB.OL  SUBC.OL TEL.OL  TOM.OL  YAR.OL
0   2020-01-02  112.500000  172.850006  984.400024  525.599976  814.000000  110.349998  208.600006  769.799988  272.500000  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2020-01-03  111.300003  171.199997  989.799988  526.799988  812.000000  107.900002  206.600006  751.400024  267.899994  ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2020-01-06  108.150002  166.100006  1001.000000 519.599976  820.200012  106.699997  206.500000  752.400024  265.600006  ... NaN NaN NaN
```

**EDIT**: here is how dataframes are created to start with:

```
def motor_daily(ticker_list):
    #function uses start and end dates to get closing prices for certain stocks.
    df = yf.download(ticker_list, start=phase_2.start(), 
end=phase_2.tomorrow()).Close
        return df
```

```
def ticker_data(list):
    #function takes "ticks" which is a list of ticker names and uses 
    #motor_daily_big_function to get data frame yahoo API
    data = []
    for ticks in list:
        data.append(motor_daily(ticks))
    return data
```

```
res = ticker_data(list_of_test)
dataframes = [pd.DataFrame(lst) for lst in res]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself, here is what I did:

```
dataframes_concat = pd.concat(dataframes)
df1 = dataframes_concat.groupby('Date', as_index=True).first()
print(df1)
AMBU-B.CO   BAVA.CO CARL-B.CO   CHR.CO  COLO-B.CO   DANSKE.CO   DEMANT.CO   DSV.CO  FLS.CO  GMAB.CO ... NHY.OL  ORK.OL  SALM.OL SCATC.OL    SCHA.OL STB.OL  SUBC.OL TEL.OL  TOM.OL  YAR.OL
Date                                                                                    
2020-01-02  112.500000  172.850006  984.400024  525.599976  814.000000  110.349998  208.600006  769.799988  272.500000  1486.5  ... 33.410000   89.959999   454.000000  123.400002  271.299988  69.900002   105.900002  157.649994  287.799988  361.299988
2020-01-03  111.300003  171.199997  989.799988  526.799988  812.000000  107.900002  206.600006  751.400024  267.899994  1444.5  ... 32.660000   89.699997   453.899994  123.000000  272.100006  69.500000   107.150002  158.800003  284.399994  356.000000
2020-01-06  108.150002  166.100006  1001.000000 519.599976  820.200012  106.699997  206.500000  752.400024  265.600006  1419.5  ... 32.299999   89.139999   453.500000  117.300003  268.299988  68.639999   108.150002  159.399994  280.000000  356.000000
2020-01-07  110.500000  170.000000  1002.000000 522.400024  823.599976  107.750000  204.399994  753.799988  273.399994  1456.0  ... 32.220001   89.879997   447.700012  116.000000  272.299988  69.720001   107.699997  156.850006  274.000000  351.399994
2020-01-08  109.599998  171.399994  993.000000  510.399994  820.000000  108.250000  205.600006  755.799988  268.000000  1466.5  ... 32.090000   87.720001   451.799988  118.400002  271.899994  70.139999   107.250000  155.449997  278.600006  357.299988
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2021-03-26  271.299988  302.000000  974.599976  548.599976  954.000000  120.050003  267.600006  1212.500000 237.800003  2045.0  ... 53.080002   84.400002   581.799988  237.600006  375.700012  83.860001   87.000000   149.050003  376.700012  444.000000
2021-03-29  281.000000  294.000000  981.400024  575.000000  968.200012  118.750000  267.100006  1206.000000 238.300003  2028.0  ... 53.060001   84.839996   585.000000  244.600006  367.399994  84.540001   87.820000   151.000000  378.500000  448.500000
2021-03-30  280.899994  282.600006  986.599976  567.400024  950.200012  120.500000  265.500000  1213.500000 243.600006  2019.0  ... 53.419998   84.800003   587.400024  246.399994  361.000000  85.400002   87.279999   150.600006  372.799988  447.200012
2021-03-31  297.899994  286.399994  974.599976  576.400024  953.799988  118.699997  268.700012  1244.500000 243.100006  2087.0  ... 54.759998   83.839996   590.000000  258.600006  359.000000  86.139999   85.900002   150.500000  370.299988  444.799988
2021-04-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

last row is NAN as markets are closed for easter.